# How to set input from bash script in an interactive shell?

Tags: mysql, linux, bash, percona

So when I install percona mysql, I get the following.

[image]

I am trying to automate sql installation using a bash script but how do I enter into the input using bash script? Enter something > hit enter.

Comment: Which package manager are you using?

Comment: I am on ubuntu.

Comment: you could use ansible and its modules for that ...

Comment: also better ask that question on Server Fault  or Ask Ubuntu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The preferred way of achieving this is using [unattended mode](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/debconf-doc/debconf.7.en.html#Unattended_Package_Installation) by setting the following environment variable before calling `apt install`:

```
export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
```

This will not prompt the user for any input but instead use the default values for everything.

If you want to supply an answer to a configuration question different to the default value, use [preseeding DebConf](http://www.microhowto.info/howto/perform_an_unattended_installation_of_a_debian_package.html).

Comment: Thank you so much. That helps. I can later change the default root password using mysql cli anyway.